# Drupal Taxonomy Module - Limiting the number of links that are displayed per tag

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I've got a site with tags like robotics, programming, simulation, quizzes etc. and I want to limit the number of links being displayed for a certain tag to a number. For example if there are 20 nodes that actually have quizzes as a tag then only 10 nodes should b displayed that have quizzes as a tag and the rest of the nodes can be displayed on clicking 'next' or 'display more' link. I'm using the taxonomy module for the tags so is it possible to make any changes in the taxonomy module code or prob. its configuration so that I am able to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is easily possible if you use the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views).

You can then set up a view that takes the term as a parameter, and using the pager, outputting no more than 20 links per page. See the screenshot of a similar view I have on one of my sites.

[screenshot of views UI http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/282/screenshot004n.png](http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/282/screenshot004n.png)

**EDIT: clarifications**

The method I am suggesting to use effectively replace the standard page you would use for the taxonomy and substitute it with the output of a view.

Views are very powerful and allow for a lot of cool features, like filtering, searching and sorting. In the example I used for the screenshot above, for example, the view replace the standard taxonomy page for the "products" of an e-commerce site.

A lighter but less flexible alternative could be to use [`theme_pager()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_pager/6).

Comment: not to mention a view that replaces the regular vocabularies and categories pages is bundled in views_ui. just turn it on, then, set the page limits ;)